# Using Statement and Connection Pooling

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, connection-pooling

I recently came to know the concept of 'connection pooling' in .NET, and as such I have a little doubt I would like anyone to clarify it for me. If I use the following piece of code, when will the database connection be returned to the pool so that it can be used by another part of the application?

```
using (SqlConnection NewConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand NewCommand = new SqlCommand("SomeCommand", NewConnection))
    {
        try
        {
            NewConnection.Open();

            // Do some work...

            NewConnection.Close(); // <-- Here?
        }
        catch
        {
            // Error handling...
        }
    }
}

// <-- Here?
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection will indeed be returned to the pool after the `using` block has finished executing.

The [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) is [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) - the compiler generates a correct [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) block which closes the connection, thus returning it to the connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the `SqlConnection` object and the **underlying** connection as separate. It is the **underlying** connection that is pooled. This is returned to the pool when the `SqlConnection` is disposed, either by explicit usage of `Dispose()`, or by a `using` block*. Later, a new (different) `SqlConnection` might be created with the same **underlying** connection.

So: the magic happens:

```
using (SqlCommand NewCommand = new SqlCommand("SomeCommand", NewConnection))
{
    ...
} <==== here
```

*=it might also (I didn't check) be released back to the pool by `GC`/finalizer - but we shouldn't focus on that because if that happens you're already doing it wrong.