# Why is my using statement not closing connection?

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Entity framework 4 not closing connection in sql server 2005 profiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114722/entity-framework-4-not-closing-connection-in-sql-server-2005-profiler)

Well, lots of developers on stackoverflow are saying that I should not worry to close my connection: my using statement will close the connection for me, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389506/ado-net-closing-connection-when-using-using-statement) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251733/using-statement-and-connection-pooling) and all over the site. Unfortunately, I do not see it happening. Here is my code:

```
    [Test, Explicit]
    public void ReconnectTest()
    {
        const string connString = "Initial Catalog=MyDb;Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=ReconnectTest;";
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = "SELECT 1 as a";
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    //conn.Close();
// optional breakpoint 1 below
                    }
                }
                catch(SqlException e)
                {
// breakpoint 2 below
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
// breakpoint 3 below
            }
        }
```

When I enable all breakpoints and start my test, the first iteration succeeds, and I hit breakpoint 3. At this point, the connection is still open: I see it in the Profiler, and sp_who2 outputs it too.

Let's suppose that at this time I am out for a lunch, and my connection is idle. As such, our production server kills it. To imitate it, I am killing the connection from SSMS.

So, when I hit F5 and run the second iteration, my connection is killed. Unfortunately, it does not reopen automatically, so ExecuteNonQuery throws the following exception: "transport-level error has occurred". When I run the third iteration, my connection actually opens: I see it as an event in Profiler, and sp_who2 outputs it as well.

Even when I have uncommented my conn.Close() command, the connection still does not close, and when I kill it from SSMS, the next iteration still blows up.

What am I missing? Why can't using statement close my connection? Why can't Open() actually open it the first time, but succeeds the next time?

This question has originated from [my previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120614/how-to-reuse-code-that-reopens-connection)

Comment: [Connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: It is an intended behavior Read about [connection reusing/pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `SqlConnection.Dispose()`, which you do because of the `using` block, the connection is not closed, per-se. It is *released back to the connection pool.*

In order to avoid constantly building/tearing down connections, the connection pool will keep connections *open* for your application to use. So it makes perfect sense that the connection would still show as being open.

What's happening after that, I can't explain offhand - I know that keeping a random connection open would *not* cause that, though, because your application can certainly make more than a single concurrent connection.